# Sticky returns break most markdown in chat

Tags: bug, chat, markdown

I typed a chat message including sticky returns (<kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Enter</kbd>), `[tag:nameoftag]` markup and `[links](http://interwebz.com)`.

The markup didn't work, it just displayed the markup itself.

A user [informed me](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32046917#32046917) that sticky returns break markup.

Is this considered a bug? It doesn't seem like intended functionality.

Comment: Sorry, it does not compute. Especially the title is incomprehensible.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Do you understand what the question this is marked as a duplicate of says? Well, it's about exactly the same thing as what I was trying to say. (English is not my native language.) You can just disregard my wording. The other question probably explains it better, so just read it there if you're interested.